# AngularJs Service, not able to store locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to save authenticated to user to variables which are local to service, but not able to see same values in second visit. Here is the code,

```
app.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$state',
function ($http, $state) {
    var currentUser = null;
    var authenticated = false;

    var setCurrentUser = function (user, flag) {
        currentUser = {};
        angular.extend(currentUser, user);
        authenticated = flag;
    };

    var getAuthenticated = function () {
        return authenticated;
    };

    var getCurrentUser = function () {
        return currentUser;
    };

    return {
        login: function (user, success, error) {
            $http.post(UserApi.login().url, user).success(function (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user, true);
                window.location.replace('/');
            }).error(error);
        },
        logout: function (success, error) {
            $http.post(UserApi.logout().url).success(function () {
                setCurrentUser(null, false);
                window.location.replace('/');
            }).error(error);
        },
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            if (getAuthenticated() && getCurrentUser() != null) return true;
            return false;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am hoping to store user details after login to `currentUser` and status to `authenticated`,
when I try to check the status of user login, these two variables are holding `null` and `false`, so I am losing user status. So how to properly store and retrieve data to ensure user is logged-in status.

Comment: I would store those details in the `sessionStorage`, so that upon refresh they would still be there.

Comment: My understanding is like, since Auth service is a singleton object which would exist all the time till I close tab/browser, please correct me in case my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Here is working example which I referred, [link](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/blob/master/client/js/services.js), here also after login user been saved to local variable, not to cookieStore.

Comment: a singleton is initialised again as well when you refresh, so you still lose your properties. In the example you gave it gets the details from the `$cookiestore` upon load as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, an Angular service is part of the JavaScript application running in-memory on the page, so as soon as you refresh the page, that service gets reconstructed. You have to select a persistence scheme and use its APIs in order to persist anything across page loads.

You have a few options:

- sessionStorage: Persisted until you close your browser window, but can be used between pages. A new tab opened to the same URL, however, will get a new empty session storage object. This is a good option just for transferring data across page refreshes.
- localStorage: Persist between windows/tabs in the same domain, and it will still be there the next time you open your browser.
- $cookieStore: An Angular wrapper over cookies, which is similar to sessionStorage except much smaller, and is included in any requests made to the server.
- [Many more esoteric choices](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) that aren't well supported by all browsers. That article is also a very good overview of web storage choices.

Really this has very little to do with Angular and is just a JavaScript persistence issue.

Here is a small example of your code using localStorage to get you started:

```
var data = angular.fromJson(localStorage['my-storage-key']) || {
    currentUser: null,
    authenticated: false
};

var save = function () {
    localStorage['my-storage-key'] = angular.toJson(data);
};

var setCurrentUser = function (user, flag) {
    data.currentUser = {};
    angular.extend(data.currentUser, user);
    data.authenticated = flag;
    save();
};

var getAuthenticated = function () {
    return data.authenticated;
};

var getCurrentUser = function () {
    return data.currentUser;
};
```

Comment: Let me add that the angular-local-storage module is great for this type of thing. http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html